# Why the maximum number of keys of opcache only accept prime numbers?

Tags: php, opcache

As you can see in the documentation the opcache.max_accelerated_files parameter only use prime numbers.

http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.max-accelerated-files

Why?

Comment: Because it's a *primed cached.* Sorry, couldn't resist. I'll be here all week, thank you.

Comment: The reason is that prime numbers lend themselves to a natural hashing function: `hash = integer%prime`